# How can I filter records in a JOIN to deal with the duplication of records?

Tags: php, mysql

Assume I have this table setup:

```
table1
  Field: t1id (int, key)
  Field: name (varchar)

table2
  Field: t2id (int, key)
  Field: parent (int) (relates to table1.t1id)
  Field: item (varchar)
```

With these data:

```
table1 (1, 'Test')
table2 (1, 1, 'Item 1')
table2 (2, 1, 'Item 2')
table2 (3, 1, 'Item 3')
```

When I do a query, I am joining the tables to get all the data.  This works, but I get back this:

```
t1id, name, item
1, 'Test', 'Item 1'
1, 'Test', 'Item 2'
1, 'Test', 'Item 3'
```

I want to loop the results and output it in a table with one row per `table1` record and one column would have all the `table2` data in it.  But if I loop on rows, it loops as many times as I have data in `table2` with the `table1` fields repeated.  Is there any way to make it return empties for `table1` other than the first hit?  Because if I do:

```
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Item</th></tr>";
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT t1id, name, item FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t1id = t2.parent");
foreach ($sql->fetchAll() AS $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "  <td>{$row["name"]}</td>";
  echo "  <td>{$row["item"]}</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

That works, but makes a row for each item from `table2`.  I got what I wanted doing this:

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Item</th></tr>";
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT t1id, name, item FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t1id = t2.parent"); 
$currow = "";
foreach ($sql->fetchAll() AS $row) {
  if ($currow != $row["name"]) {
    if (!empty($currow)) echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>{$row["name"]}</td>";
    echo "  <td>{$row["item"]}<br/>";
    $currow = $row["name"];
  } else {
    echo "{$row["item"]}<br/>";
  }
}
```

...but that feels *really* hacky.  What would the right way to do it be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iteration is generally the way to do it.

Because of the way you use `item`, the following will `GROUP_CONCAT`inate it for you. Generally this is putting more load on the DB server where as your application servers are more scalable.

```
SELECT t1id, name, GROUP_CONCAT( item  SEPARATOR '<br/>') as itemconcat
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t1id = t2.parent
GROUP BY t1id
```

Answer (score 0):

i think will be better prepare data for output.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($sql->fetchAll() AS $row) {
    $result[$row["name"]][] = $row["item"]
}
```

and after output the data

```
<?php foreach($result as $name=>$items):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$name?></td>
    <td><?=implode("<br/>", $items)?></td>
  </tr>
<?phpendforeach;?>
```